Непонятный ответ VK API на метод notifications.get
При вызове метода notifiations.get с этими параметрами:
filters:wall,mentions,comments,likes,reposts,followers,friends
end_time:1721646831
start_time:1716462831
count:20
Я получаю подобную структуру объектов в массиве items:
{
"inner_type": "notifications_unified_notification",
        "id": "g5_0_1721634633_425430276",
        "date": 1721634633,
        "main_item": {
            "type": "user",
            "object_id": "425430276",
            "image_object": []
        },
        "hide_buttons": [{
            "label": "\u0421\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c \u0443\u0432\u0435\u0434\u043e\u043c\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f",
            "action": {
                "type": "hide_item",
                "context": {
                    "query": "PUkbF1tQSVx1W1FCBgJeUn5HSxtQQAMJIklTVFJGBBM2NAwYUl0FA2RHSwJMRA45Lw9LTAAYSQkkAQwVQRZRPWtaWUUEBV1WclhFRAIDWFYbR0sCWmsfFWRRWEEHBV1Vcl1aRRkWDRQpBjYCRhZRV3FZWEMMAV1WdkdLH1FRBRIvDQATRxZRRCFeNkZqBVxUd11aQgMHWDlyWVxCBgRZUXBJFA",
                    "snackbar_text": "\u0423\u0432\u0435\u0434\u043e\u043c\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0441\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044b"
                }
            },
            "style": "none",
            "short_label": "\u0421\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c",
            "destructive": false
        }, {
            "label": "\u041f\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0437\u044b\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0440\u0435\u0436\u0435",
            "action": {
                "type": "hide_item",
                "context": {
                    "query": "PUkbF1tQSVx3XFtAAARaV3NTRVRYUR8OKQ9LTBdTGQkzGzYTW1MCCCNJRVRBTRsDGQINVA8BR0QpCQMTVkBJXB1GWEYGBVpQdl9aWgcDXFV2NkVUQVs0EjVJU0cCBlpQdV9fRQYYSQA0BAQpQUdJXHdcW0cADV5QdltFVFxQDggyAg8fUEZJXGQMXCkFa1pRdFpfRQECWFUZX1tDAQdbVHFdS1oXXQYWKRkdF1tASVx2R0sFXVscOSoOGgVqVwQIMg4RAhcOSQkkATZDahlaVnVaWEAFAFg5dFxeRQUWFg",
                    "snackbar_text": "\u041f\u043e\u0445\u043e\u0436\u0438\u0435 \u0443\u0432\u0435\u0434\u043e\u043c\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0431\u0443\u0434\u0443\u0442 \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0437\u044b\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f \u0440\u0435\u0436\u0435"
                }
            },
            "style": "none",
            "destructive": false
        }],
        "icon_type": "like",
        "footer": "{date}",
        "header": "'''[id425430276|\u0410\u043d\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0439 \u0421\u043c\u0438\u0440\u043d\u043e\u0432]''' \u0438 \u0435\u0449\u0451 '''3''' \u0447\u0435\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0435\u043a\u0430 \u043e\u0446\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0432\u0430\u0448\u0443 \u0437\u0430\u043f\u0438\u0441\u044c [https:\/\/vk.com\/wall-103116043_27730|Windows 10 22H2] \u0432 \u0441\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0435 [club103116043|Windows Vista with Service Pack 2 \/ 2024]",
        "attachments": [{
            "type": "user",
            "object_id": "744440832",
            "image_object": []
        }, {
            "type": "user",
            "object_id": "401140239",
            "image_object": []
        }, {
            "type": "user",
            "object_id": "337547666",
            "image_object": []
        }],
        "additional_item": {
            "type": "photo",
            "object_id": "-103116043_457245630",
            "image_object": [],
            "action": {
                "type": "custom",
                "url": "https:\/\/vk.com\/wall-103116043_27730"
            }
        },
        "action": {
            "type": "custom",
            "url": "https:\/\/vk.com\/wall-103116043_27730"
        },
        "buttons": [],
        "button_hide": false,
        "show_csat": false
    }

Хотя в документации, даже более того, в интернете нет ни одного упоминания о данной структуре...
Что это вообще такое???
Для получения access_token я исполльзую client_id приложения ВК для iOS.
